# Всем привет, помогите с установкой node-sass

Tags: css, node.js, sass

https://webdesign-master.ru/blog/tools/2016-06-04-sass.html

Пошла по этому гайду и выполнила все пункты, но вылазит ошибка при выполнении gulp

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (88)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:13:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:991:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:166:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
```

Comment: А вы не пробовали загуглить ошибку? Первый же сайт - решение

Comment: Да, вот только гугл не помог, поэтому пришла сюда

Comment: Если Гугл не помог, приложите свои попытки решить проблему

Comment: @Voprositel, если я сюда задала вопрос, то наверное подразумевается, что я приложила усилия и у меня ничего не вышло.

Comment: И тем не менее в Гугл огромное кол-во решений. На этом сайте принято прикладывать свои попытки решения проблемы

Comment: переустановите пакет

Answer (score 0):

Согласно приведенной вами статье, вы установили `node-sass` глобально, что и повлекло за собой ошибку. Впредь лучше вообще не устанавливайте `node-sass` глобально, в 99 из 100 случаев работать не будет.

Устанавливайте локально с помощью `npm i node-sass`, т.е. тоже самое, но без флага `-g`.